# import a complicated file containing letters and numbers

Tags: import

I have a complicated file [here](https://gofile.io/?c=mwa5Da) as a text file which contains numbers and letters. There is a number with value `-13.997315618223263` at line 13:

```
      <SCALAR_AVERAGE name="Eng"><MEAN>-13.997315618223263</MEAN></SCALAR_AVERAGE>
```

I cannot import the file as `table`. Is there any way to import the file and extract this value?
It seems that if I copy and past is easier way but I have a lot of files every which includes a number (albeit different values). I wish to prevent opening each file individually and copying the value.

Comment: That looks like `XML`. There's an XML parser inside Mathematica.

Comment: The file has xml format. I thought it is difficult to import, then I changed it to a dat file. I did not know there is a way to import xml files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with importing as XML is that the file is not a complete XML document, it is missing an outer enclosing tag. One way to get around that is to add a tag, import as XML, and extract the value of the `MEAN` element:

```
testString = Import["~/Downloads/test.dat", "Text"];
testXML = ImportString["<test>" <> testString <> "</test>", "XML"];
Cases[testXML, XMLElement["MEAN", __], Infinity] // Map[Last] // ToExpression

(* {{-13.9973}, {-13.8796}} *)
```

Comment: You are very intelligent!!!

Answer (score 1):

The imported data usually is an array of strings. Thus, you should parse the strings to take the numbers. The principle of parsing depend on the your understanding of the structure of file content. This is usual way for any text-processing.

Looking onto your string, I supposed that desired numbers sit between tags **Mean**. So, just search for position of them in the string and take the substring from the between.

```
str = "<SCALAR_AVERAGE \
name=\"Eng\"><MEAN>-13.997315618223263</MEAN></SCALAR_AVERAGE>";

number=ToExpression@StringTake[str,
  {Last@First@StringPosition[str, "<MEAN>"] + 1, 
   First@First@StringPosition[str, "</MEAN>"] - 1}]
```

Comment: This line is in the body of a file. Do you mean I should copy `"<SCALAR_AVERAGE \
name=\"Eng\"><MEAN> A Value</MEAN></SCALAR_AVERAGE>"` for each file?

Comment: @InzoBabaria, I guess, you can do easy `data=Import[...]` without additional help from my side. Each `data[[i]]` will be equivalent to the `str`

Comment: Thank you so much. I extracted it by `str = data[[13]]`. It likes as `{"<SCALAR_AVERAGE", \
"name=\"Eng\"><MEAN>-13.997315618223263</MEAN></SCALAR_AVERAGE>"}`. It means that we have additional `{....}`. So sorry for my question: How can we remove `{ }` to reach the internal expression i.e.,  `"<SCALAR_AVERAGE \
name=\"Eng\"><MEAN>-13.997315618223263</MEAN></SCALAR_AVERAGE>"`

Comment: @InzoBabaria, In your case the data is a list of lists. Therefore, you should use an additional index when take the string: `str=data[[i,1]];` This `1` will "remove" one level of brackets `{..}` Or alternatively you can use `str=First@data[[i]];`